# How to smooth data of increasing noise

Tags: r, modeling, spline

Chemist here (so not very good with statistical analysis) and novice in R:

I have various sets of data where the yield of a reaction is monitored with time such as:

- The data:

  `df <- structure(list(time = c(15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 
  150, 165, 180, 195, 210, 225, 240, 255, 270, 285, 300, 315, 330, 
  345, 360, 375, 390, 405, 420, 435, 450, 465, 480, 495, 510, 525, 
  540, 555, 570, 585, 600, 615, 630, 645, 660, 675, 690, 705, 720, 
  735, 750, 765, 780, 795, 810, 825, 840, 855, 870, 885, 900, 915, 
  930, 945, 960, 975, 990, 1005, 1020, 1035, 1050, 1065, 1080, 
  1095, 1110, 1125, 1140, 1155, 1170, 1185, 1200, 1215, 1230, 1245, 
  1260, 1275, 1290, 1305, 1320, 1335, 1350, 1365, 1380, 1395, 1410, 
  1425, 1440, 1455, 1470, 1485, 1500, 1515, 1530, 1545, 1560, 1575, 
  1590, 1605, 1620, 1635, 1650, 1665, 1680, 1695, 1710, 1725, 1740, 
  1755, 1770, 1785, 1800, 1815, 1830, 1845, 1860, 1875, 1890, 1905, 
  1920, 1935, 1950, 1965, 1980, 1995, 2010, 2025, 2040, 2055, 2070, 
  2085, 2100, 2115, 2130), yield = c(9.3411, 9.32582, 10.5475, 
  13.5358, 17.3376, 16.7444, 20.7234, 19.8374, 24.327, 27.4162, 
  27.38, 31.3926, 29.3289, 32.2556, 33.0025, 35.3358, 35.8986, 
  40.1859, 40.3886, 42.2828, 41.23, 43.8108, 43.9391, 43.9543, 
  48.0524, 47.8295, 48.674, 48.2456, 50.2641, 50.7147, 49.6828, 
  52.8877, 51.7906, 57.2553, 53.6175, 57.0186, 57.6598, 56.4049, 
  57.1446, 58.5464, 60.7213, 61.0584, 57.7481, 59.9151, 64.475, 
  61.2322, 63.5167, 64.6289, 64.4245, 62.0048, 65.5821, 65.8275, 
  65.7584, 68.0523, 65.4874, 68.401, 68.1503, 67.8713, 69.5478, 
  69.9774, 73.4199, 66.7266, 70.4732, 67.5119, 69.6107, 70.4911, 
  72.7592, 69.3821, 72.049, 70.2548, 71.6336, 70.6215, 70.8611, 
  72.0337, 72.2842, 76.0792, 75.2526, 72.7016, 73.6547, 75.6202, 
  76.5013, 74.2459, 76.033, 78.4803, 76.3058, 73.837, 74.795, 76.2126, 
  75.1816, 75.3594, 79.9158, 77.8157, 77.8152, 75.3712, 78.3249, 
  79.1198, 77.6184, 78.1244, 78.1741, 77.9305, 79.7576, 78.0261, 
  79.8136, 75.5314, 80.2177, 79.786, 81.078, 78.4183, 80.8013, 
  79.3855, 81.5268, 78.416, 78.9021, 79.9394, 80.8221, 81.241, 
  80.6111, 79.7504, 81.6001, 80.7021, 81.1008, 82.843, 82.2716, 
  83.024, 81.0381, 80.0248, 85.1418, 83.1229, 83.3334, 83.2149, 
  84.836, 79.5156, 81.909, 81.1477, 85.1715, 83.7502, 83.8336, 
  83.7595, 86.0062, 84.9572, 86.6709, 84.4124)), .Names = c("time", 
  "yield"), row.names = c(NA, -142L), class = "data.frame")`
- What i want to do to the data:

I need to smooth the data in order to plot the 1st derivative. In the paper the author mentioned that one can fit a high order polynomial and use that to do the processing which i think is wrong since we dont really know the true relationship between time and yield for the data and is definitely not polyonymic. I tried regardless and the plot of the derivative did not make any chemical sense as expected. Next i looked into loess using: `loes<-loess(Yield~Time,data=df,span=0.9)` which gave a much better fit. However, the best results so far was using :

```
spl <- smooth.spline(df$Time, y=df$Yield,cv=TRUE)
colnames(predspl)<-c('Time','Yield')
pred.der<-as.data.frame(predict(spl, deriv=1))
colnames(pred.der)<-c('Time', 'Yield')
```

which gave the best fit especially in the initial data points (by visual inspection).

- The problem i have:

The issue however is that the derivative looks really good only up to t=500s and then it starts wiggling more and more towards the end. This shouldnt happen from a chemistry point of view and it is just a result of overfitting towards the end of the data due to the increase of the noise. I know this since for some experiments that i have performed 3 times and averaged the data (so the noise decreased) the wiggling is much smaller in the plot of the derivative.

- What i have tried so far:

I tried different values of spar which although it smoothens correctly the later data it causes a poor fit in the initial data (which are the most important). I also tried to reduce the number of knots but i got a similar result with the one from changing the spar value. What i think i need is to have a larger amount of knots in the begining which will smoothly decrease to a small number of knots towards the end to avoid that overfitting.

- The question:

Is my reasoning correct here? Does anyone know how can i have the above effect in order to get a smooth derivative without any wiggling? Do i need to try a different fit other than the spline maybe? I have attached a pic in the end where you can see the derivative from the smooth.spline vs time and a black line (drawn by hand) of what it should look like. Thank you for your help in advance.

[image]

Comment: Your fitted spline uses a rather high number of degrees of freedom (> 11), you could try limiting that to a lower number for a smoother fit

Comment: Or, you could try to specify the knots manually, to better capture regions of interest in the derivative: the flat part at the start, fast decline, and leveling off.

Comment: The relevant arguments to `smooth.spline` would be `df` and `all.knots`

Comment: I have tried lowering the df but although the resulting derivative is of the shape i would like, the fit is poor in the initial data and therefore gives a wrong result. The all.knots argument just changes the number of knots eveny spaced across the data. I dont think you can make it so it has a smaller spacing in the beginning and large in the end (correct me if i am wrong). Other than that, that was my thought as well! I have started thinking that i might need to look into the mgcv package since there might not be a quick simple solution to this. :(

Comment: Which version of R are you using? When I commented earlier I was on 3.4.3, and to my surprise the option to set knot locations using `all.knots` wasn't there on 3.3.2 that I'm using now

Comment: You are spot on on the R version: I updated and now i can set the knots manually.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track on having more closely spaced knots for the spline at the start of the curve. You can specify knot locations for `smooth.spline` using `all.knots` (at least on R >= 3.4.3; I skimmed the release notes for R, but couldn't pinpoint the version where this became available).

Below is an example, and the resulting, smoother fit for the derivative after some manual work of trying out different knot positions:

```r
with(df, {
  kn <- c(0, c(50, 100, 200, 350, 500, 1500) / max(time), 1)
  s <- smooth.spline(time, yield, cv = T)
  s2 <- smooth.spline(time, yield, all.knots = kn)

  ds <- predict(s, d = 1)
  ds2 <- predict(s2, d = 1)

  np <- list(mfrow = c(2, 1), mar = c(4, 4, 1, 2))
  withr::with_par(np, {
    plot(time, yield)
    lines(s)
    lines(s2, lty = 2, col = 'red')

    plot(ds, type = 'l', ylim = c(0, 0.15))
    lines(ds2, lty = 2, col = 'red')
  })
})
```

[image]

You can probably fine tune the locations further, but I wouldn't be too concerned about it. The primary fits are already near enough indistinguishable, and I'd say you're asking quite a lot from these data in terms of identifying details about the derivative (this should be evident if you `plot(time[-1], diff(yield) / diff(time))` which gives you an impression about the level of information your data carry about the derivative).

Created on 2018-02-15 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: I tried the above and after a lot of messing around with knot positions as well i did manage to get to the correct fit by comparing the derivative of the noisy data with the derivative of the data which were the average of the experiment perforemed 3 times for wich the noise was lower (and for which i got a good spline fit without any special settings). The question that remains is whether there is a better way to smooth such data than the spline so i can avoid the dodgy manual  manipulation.

Comment: I'd say short of specifying a fully parametric model that has the shape of derivative you want, it seems unlikely. There's only so much you can do with variable data.

Comment: Also, it's only made harder by the fact that you only have one measurement per time point, as you've correctly noted.

Comment: But as it sounds like you have strong prior beliefs of how the derivative should be shaped, I think you could get somewhere with exploring some parametric models.

Comment: Then again, you could try using a natural cubic spline with just two knots, to capture the three main regions of interest in the derivative: `lm(yield ~ ns(time, knots = c(100, 1200)), data = df)`. You are likely to get a somewhat worse fit, though, as that's effectively estimating the function as 3 pasted-together 3rd order polynomials, but that limits the derivative to containing 2nd order polynomial terms.